# Magento checkout Observer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, observers

I have created a custom module that will allow me to add and manage multiple store locations. I have managed to add a custom payment method and when the user selects this, a dropdown appears that shows all the available stores. I have added an installer script that adds a column on the following databases: `sales_flat_order`, `sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_order_quote`. The column is called `store_pickup_id`. What I am trying to do is have the sales quote and sale order save the store pickup id, but I cannot seem to do it. I have created the following observer that extends `sales_quote_save_after` event

```
public function saveCustomData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $quote = $event->getQuote();

        $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();

        if (isset($post["store_pickup"])) {
            $quote->setStorePickupId($post["store_pickup"]);
        }

        Mage::log("Store pickup id: ".$quote->getStorePickupId());

        return $this;
    }
```

When I do a test transaction, I can see in `sales_flat_quote` that the `store_pickup_id` is getting set as it saves between steps. However, when I process the order, another entry is added to the same table, but without the `store_pickup_id` and the order also fails to have the `store_pickup_id` set.

Anyone know how I can get this custom data to save into the quote and order?

Comment: You probably need to add this same observer to the order when a quote is converted... You may need to do this at every step of the transaction process. Not sure which particular observer you need to add but here is the list of events: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the link. I am actually already using this link and have already tried sales_convert_quote_to_order event, but still the same result

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution, turns out I was missing the following key lines in my config which will convert my custom data to the order

```
<fieldsets>
    <sales_convert_quote>
        <store_pickup_id>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
        </store_pickup_id>
    </sales_convert_quote>
</fieldsets>
```

I found the following [link](http://adeptasoftware.co.uk/blog/magento-delivery-date-extension-part-3/) very helpfull, hope it helps others